# Dart: using variables as method placeholders

Tags: flutter, dart

Using this function:

```
buildButton(int file_number, String yourcolor, [String text]){
  return Expanded(
  child: FlatButton(
  color: Colors.yourcolor,
  child: Text(text),
  onPressed: (){
    playaudio(file_number);
    },
  ),);
}
```

On `color: Colors.yourcolor`. I keep getting the error:

`The getter 'yourcolor' isn't defined for the class 'Colors'.
Try importing the library that defines 'yourcolor', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'yourcolor'.`

I am aware that there isn't a method named 'yourcolor' but is there a way i can get the color i want using a function parameter?

Comment: You do realize that you are passing a string to the Colors object. So what you are doing is `Colors.'blue'`, which will result as an error. As far as I know, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "method placeholder", but in your case, you either will need to write and call your own function that maps `String`s to `Color`s or use an existing package that provides such a mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin) i was able to create a map that points 'yourcolor' to it's corresponding color

```
buildButton(int file_number, String yourcolor){
  Map match_colors = {'red':Colors.red, 'orange':Colors.orange, 'yellow':Colors.yellow,
  'lightgreen': Colors.lightGreen, 'green':Colors.green, 'lightblue':Colors.lightBlue, 'purple':Colors.purple};

  return Expanded(
  child: FlatButton(
  color: match_colors[yourcolor],
  onPressed: (){
    playaudio(file_number);
    },
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use String to pass the color. You have to pass the color itself.

```
    buildButton(int file_number, Color yourcolor, [String text]){
        return Expanded(
        child: FlatButton(
            color: yourcolor,
            child: Text(text),
            onPressed: (){
                playaudio(file_number);
            },
        ),);
     }
```

and when you call the function pass the color as `Colors.blue` for example.